# How to de-register or override a registered ServiceProvider at run-time from a package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, service-provider

I am registering my own custom FormBuilder and HtmlBuilder classes which extend the native Laravel counterparts in a composer package. However, I have had a difficult time to get them to be recognized in my app at run-time without manually removing `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'` from the providers array in app.php config.

I need to be able to achieve this somehow at run-time.

1. Is there a way to override registered service providers at run-time?
2. If not, is there a way to remove registered service providers at run-time?
3. Is there a better/more effective/more efficient method to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of that array, is so you can replace dependencies with your own... Go ahead and change/remove it :)

Comment: I need to do this at run-time, since it is a composer package, and may or may not be installed. So somehow I would like to update the application object and remove the registered service provider before adding the composer package's service provider at run-time during the registration process. For this use-case editing app.php unfortunately won't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove a service from service provider, just make it null. Or, replace it with your service.

```
app()->instance(SomeClass::class, null);
```